# php passing array to class function

Tags: php

Hello i want to pass array to my class function but i am not getting the value . plz help me out what is the problem with this sample code

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submituser']))
{
$user = new User();
$user->connect();
$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];

$result = array($name=>$name,$age=>$age);


$user->setUser($result);

$user->disconnect();
}
?>
```

and the class function is like this

```
function setUser($result) 
{
echo $result[$name];
$errors_all = array();
$validate = new Validator();
$validate->addRequiredFieldValidator($result[$name],"First name is required.")."";
}
```

i can get by $result[0] by i want to get it by value 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing it, you should not have the `$` in the array key.  Instead they should be quoted strings:

```
// Incorrect:
$result = array($name=>$name,$age=>$age);

// Should be:
$result = array('name'=>$name,'age'=>$age);
```

Answer (score 4):

The way your code is written, if my name is `Jay` and I am `31` years old, the array will look like this...

```
{
'Jay' => 'Jay',
'31' => 31
}
```

The keys should be constant strings, and not (in this case) variables, as indicated by the `$` sign.

Try this instead.

```
$result = array(
    'name'=>$name,
    'age'=>$age
);
```

This will yield

```
{
'name' => 'Jay',
'age' => 31
}
```

**Important** you must also change the way you are echo'ing your array values

```
//echo $result[$name];
echo $result['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Man . Finally it worked after wasting 3 hrs ,Your solution worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome. Please do see what you can do about visiting your old questions and accepting answers (by clicking the checkmark next to the correct answer). Otherwise, people will be hesitant to help you in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/users/592344/umar